# VBA macro to add any number of slides with a picture in each slide

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I am new to VBA. I am using powerpoint to write a VBA code to add n number of slides and each slide should contain selected picture from the selected path. I have tried following code which is only adding one slide and also a different macro for adding picture to each slide. So my problem is for example i would like to have 40 slides with selected picture to all the slides. Any type of hint would be appreciated.

code to add slide:

```
Public Sub Add_Example() 

Dim pptSlide As Slide 
Dim pptLayout As CustomLayout 

Set pptLayout = ActivePresentation.Slides(1).CustomLayout 
Set pptSlide = ActivePresentation.Slides.AddSlide(2, pptLayout)

End Sub
```

Comment: This has been asked and answered many times. Try Googling _PowerPoint VBA folder full of pictures_

Answer (score 1):

You can use loops for your goal.

Public Sub Add_Example()

Dim pptSlide as Slide
Dim pptLayout As CustomLayout
Dim SlideCount as Integer
Dim FilePath as String

SlideCount = 40
' add your file path
FilePath = " Your path of file "

Set pptLayout = ActivePresentation.Slides(1).CustomLayout

For i=1 to SlideCount

Set pptSlide = ActivePresentation.Slides.AddSlide(i+1, pptLayout)

pptSlide.Shapes.AddPicture FileName:=FilePath, LinkToFile:=msoFalse, SaveWithDocument:=msoTrue, Left:=100, Top:=100

Next

End Sub